# Section of the html web page not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am beginner to bootstrap and building a website using HTML5 and bootstrap.
It was working fine. After 2 days, some page contents are not displaying. That particular section and container is not displaying.

What may be the issue and solutions?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yvpq.png)

Comment: You gotta post more specifics. A static image, poorly formatted, isn't going to cut it. We need to see code or a fiddle to help.

Comment: I gotta agree with the others, you need to show some code or website link to go with the image. Can't really help without proper info. Post your code here or in jsfiddle or pastebin, etc.

Comment: Please do not encourage anyone to only post a link to an external source. The relevant code should always be posted as part of the question. You know, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using some online css file. In this case if you are offline, your browser can't loud the css files.

for example: if you are using css like this,

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

please download bootstrap file and put in your project folder and use like this to can use this in offline mode too;

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
```